# Convert associative array elements to object only

Tags: php

My array

```
$arr = array(
  "name" => "Prakash",
  "tall" => "maybe",
  "nick_names" => array ("p", "b", "bee", "prak", "new_names" => array("short_name" =>   "sn", "long_name" => "ln"))
);
```

I want to be able to create an object from which the values can be accessed via attributes.

e.g.

```
 $obj->name // "PRAKASH"
 $obj->nick_names // array("p", "b", "bee", "prak", "new_names" => (object))
```

How could I get this ?

I seem to able to accomplish exactly what I need through

```
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr));
```

But obviously that is not the right thing to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it into an `stdClass`:

```
$obj = (stdClass) $arr;
```

Take note that in PHP an array is far superior to an `stdClass` in any thinkable way.

- Better performance
- Better traversing abilities
- Better readability (IMO)

Comment: @Matt: None. An array is better in any way (performance, traversing abilities, readability). Not sure why OP even wants this.

Comment: Did you mean $obj = (object) $arr ? As (stdClass) $arr, does not work. Although, (object) casting does not convert to "new_names" key into an object. (do check the description, I added in the new key under "nick_names")

Comment: @PrakashRaman: You want to recursively cast all arrays into an object. In which case you're just better off using json_decode and json_encode. The question remains, why would you want such a thing? An array is better in every way.

Comment: Right. The only reason (for me, a real big one) is that gets cleaner and quicker. And most importantly, I will be able to chain.

Comment: @PrakashRaman: It will not get cleaner, it will not get quicker, and arrays allow you to chain as well. `$arr["nick_names"]["new_names"]["long_name"]` vs `$obj->nick_names->new_names->long_name`

Comment: I meant quicker while typing. But I get what you mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15193/discussion-between-prakash-raman-and-truth)